# Как собрать несколько строк в одну, исключив NULL-значения? SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Предположим, есть таблица заявок, которая отображает какая группа в организации во сколько взялась за неё. Количество групп может быть любым (соответственно, столько же строк с этой заявкой в таблице). Как отобразить эту же таблицу, но вместо 5 строк с разными группами вывести 1 строку с этой заявкой, а все группы вывести в столбцах в хронологическом порядке? Я подошел к следующему коду:

```
-- Завожу переменные
declare @query varchar(MAX) = 'SELECT DISTINCT [Обращение_ID],'
declare @item varchar(50)
declare @max_count int = (select TOP 1 COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY [Обращение_ID]) FROM V_SCTimeEntries2_1049)

-- Формирую числовую последовательность до максимально количества вхождений
declare cur cursor for 
    select top (@max_count) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Обращение_UID] ) from V_SCTimeEntries2_1049

-- Формирую запрос с динамическим количеством столбцов
open cur
fetch cur into @item
while @@fetch_status = 0 begin
    set @query = @query + ' case WHEN RN='+@item+' then [РабочаяГруппа] end [Группа ' + @item + '],'
    fetch cur into @item
end
set @query = 
    LEFT(@query, LEN(@query) - 1) + ' ' +
    'FROM (select *,  '+
    'ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Обращение_ID] ORDER BY [НазначеноВГруппу]) RN, ' +
    'COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY [Обращение_ID]) CNT ' +
    'FROM V_SCTimeEntries2_1049) numbered_V_SCTimeEntries2_1049'
execute(@query)
close cur
deallocate cur
```

В итоге получаю не совсем то, что хотелось бы
[image: Скриншот таблицы]

А хотелось бы, чтобы первые 4 строки из скриншота собрались в одну:

SC-0000067 | Служба технической поддержки | Продажи - 2 линия | Продажи - 3 линия | Продажи - 3 линия |

SC-0000068 | Служба технической поддержки | NULL | NULL  | NULL |

SC-0000069 | Служба технической поддержки | NULL | NULL  | NULL |

Отсюда вопрос: **Как бы эти строки собрать в одну?**

Comment: Можете привести скрипт создания и заполнения тестовыми данными таблицы `V_SCTimeEntries2_1049`?

Comment: Обернуть итоговый запрос еще в один, выполнить `group by [Обращение_ID]` и получать max от групп. Или может получится отказаться от оконных функций и просто выполнять сразу group by

Comment: Тоже думал насчет внешнего запрос со взятием максимума, но во-первых длинный запрос получается (т.к. внешний тоже нужно сделать динамическим, т.к. количество столбцов не известно), во-вторых как-то слишком уж "в лоб". Предположил, что возможно внутренний запрос сформулировать лучше, уповая на опыт комьюнити. В принципе, в БД всего 5 тысяч строк, но это сейчас.

Comment: Возможно, стоит подумать над тем стоит ли данные хранить в таком виде?

Comment: "Мопед не мой". Шеф хочет получать всю инфу по заявке одной строкой (а количество групп таки не известно), против тз не попрешь.

Comment: Запрос получающий max_count очень странный. он получает count() в разрезе обращений и берет _первый попавшийся_, а не максимальный, потому что нет никакой сортировки. И кстати, непонятно зачем вообще применена оконная функция, если там более уместен обычный group by

Comment: И если бы вы все таки привели исходные данные в текстовом виде, как вас попросил  vikolyada, возможно даже ответ бы получили ... И еще неплохо было бы увидеть запрос который сейчас получается в чистом виде, без кода его сборщика. Т.е. переделать примерный запрос с фиксированным кол-вом групп будет заметно проще, чем копаться в коде сборщика. А сборщик уже сами потом допиилите под новый запрос

Comment: Насчет формирования @max_count, вы правы (переделывал готовый скрипт из интернета, я не очень опытен в SQL, т.к. это не основное моё направление). Теперь это звучит как:

`declare @max_count int = (select TOP 1 COUNT(1) CT FROM V_SCTimeEntries2_1049 GROUP BY [Обращение_ID] ORDER BY CT DESC)`

Comment: Еще посмотрите примеры https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069024/ потому как селектить порядковые номера из таблицы как то странно. лучше уж сделать простенький цикл от 1 до N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не нужно использовать курсор, достаточно цикла. Вот пример с использованием `PIVOT`:

```
DECLARE 
   @query varchar(max),    -- запрос
   @GroupCountMax INT,     -- максимальное число групп во всех обращениях
   @step INT = 1;          -- счетчик цикла для построения запроса

-- получаем максимальное число групп во всех обращениях
SELECT TOP (1)
   @GroupCountMax = COUNT(*)
FROM V_SCTimeEntries2_1049
GROUP BY [Обращение_ID]
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC

-- формируем начало запроса
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
   [Обращение_ID],
   [Порядковый номер группы] = ''Группа '' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY [Обращение_ID] ORDER BY [НазначеноВГруппу]) AS VARCHAR),
   [РабочаяГруппа]
FROM V_SCTimeEntries2_1049 t) as p
PIVOT (MAX([РабочаяГруппа]) FOR [Порядковый номер группы] IN ('

-- формируем столбцы в PIVOT
WHILE @step <= @GroupCountMax
BEGIN;
   IF @step < @GroupCountMax
      SET @query += '[Группа ' + CAST(@step AS VARCHAR) + '], ';
   ELSE
      SET @query += '[Группа ' + CAST(@step AS VARCHAR) + '])) AS pvt;';
   SET @step += 1;
END;

-- выполняем
EXEC (@query);
```

Comment: У вас гораздо красивее решение, поэтому отмечу его за верное для вновь пришедших пользователей. Здесь рядом лежит способ, которым решил я. Что ж, опыт - дело наживное.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге, принял во внимание комментарии и получилось так. Не самый элегантный способ, понимаю, но идея с PIVOT пришла позже, поэтому не успела уйти в реализацию. Выполняется за секунду, поэтому все-таки имеет право на жизнь.

```
-- Завожу переменные
declare @query varchar(MAX)
declare @item varchar(50)
declare @max_count int = (select TOP 1 COUNT(1) CT FROM V_SCTimeEntries2_1049 GROUP BY [Обращение_ID] ORDER BY CT DESC)

-- Формирую числовую последовательность до максимально количества вхождений
declare cur cursor for 
    select top (@max_count) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Обращение_UID] ) from V_SCTimeEntries2_1049

-- Формирую запрос с динамическим количеством столбцов
open cur
set @query = 'SELECT DISTINCT [Обращение_UID], [Обращение_ДатаСоздания], [Обращение_СрокSLA], min(DateDiff(hour, [Обращение_ДатаСоздания],[Обращение_СрокSLA])) as [SLA], [Обращение_ФактОкончание], CNT-1 AS [Количество эскалаций], MAX([ГруппаРешившаяЗаявку]) [ГруппаРешившаяЗаявку],'
fetch cur into @item
while @@fetch_status = 0 begin
    set @query = @query + ' MAX([Группа ' + @item + ']) [Группа ' + @item + '],'
        + ' MAX([НазначеноВГруппу ' + @item + ']) [НазначеноВГруппу ' + @item + '],'
        + ' MAX([ОбработкаЗавершена ' + @item + ']) [ОбработкаЗавершена ' + @item + '],'
    fetch cur into @item
end
set @query = 
    LEFT(@query, LEN(@query) - 1) + ' ' +
    'FROM ('
close cur
open cur
set @query = @query+ 'SELECT DISTINCT *, case WHEN RN=CNT then [РабочаяГруппа] end [ГруппаРешившаяЗаявку],'
fetch cur into @item
while @@fetch_status = 0 begin
    set @query = @query 
        + ' case WHEN RN='+@item+' then [РабочаяГруппа] end [Группа ' + @item + '],' 
        + ' case WHEN RN='+@item+' then [НазначеноВГруппу] end [НазначеноВГруппу ' + @item + '],' 
        + ' case WHEN RN='+@item+' then [ОбработкаЗавершена] end [ОбработкаЗавершена ' + @item + '],'
    fetch cur into @item
end
set @query = 
    LEFT(@query, LEN(@query) - 1) + ' ' +
    'FROM (select *,  '+
    'ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Обращение_ID] ORDER BY [НазначеноВГруппу]) RN, ' +
    'COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY [Обращение_ID]) CNT ' +
    'FROM V_SCTimeEntries2_1049) numbered_V_SCTimeEntries2_1049) leveled_numbered_V_SCTimeEntries2_1049 '+
    'WHERE CNT>1 ' + 
    'GROUP BY [Обращение_UID], [Обращение_ДатаСоздания], [Обращение_СрокSLA], [Обращение_ФактОкончание], CNT-1'
close cur
deallocate cur
execute(@query)
```